# Please give me an example of $a \in K-R$ but there exists $n\in\mathbb{N}$, $a^n\in R$

Tags: commutative-algebra

Suppose $R$ is integral domain and $K$ is the fraction field of $R$. Please give me an example of $a \in K-R$ but there exists $n\in\mathbb{N}$, $a^n\in R$.

Comment: I think you mean $n \in \mathbb{Z}, n\geq 2.$ otherwise it would be very trivial. for example take $R = \mathbb{Z}, a = \frac{1}{2}, n = -1$

Comment: Excuse me $n \in \mathbb(N)$.

Answer (score 2):

a) $R=\mathbb Q[T^2, T^3]\subset K=\mathbb Q(T), a=T, n=2$.
b) $R=\mathbb Z[2i]\subset \mathbb Q(i), a=i, n=2$
c) etc $\cdots$

I think you get the idea. The key concept here is [*(non-) integrally closed*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integrally_closed_domain) .

Comment: Or better say *non root closed*. (In commutative algebra there is also the concept of [root closure](http://journals.cambridge.org/download.php?file=%2FGMJ%2FGMJ31_01%2FS0017089500007618a.pdf&code=d135764aa96fad635367dab8427fc72d) of an integral domain.)

Comment: @user26857: well, yes, but "root closed" is not a very widespread concept in commutative algebra or algebraic geometry...